# RCP update site for multiple platforms

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

I've got an RCP application built for several platforms. The target with delta pack is set OK, Product Export Wizard works OK, PDE ant build works OK. But the Update Site project creates the updates only for the single platform - the one I use for development actually (win32). I expect the update site to include all the dependencies from all platforms required by the listed features.. Any ideas what could go wrong and where to look?

Comment: How do you create the update site, from Eclipse IDE or do you use a headless way?

Comment: Update site is done in eclipse IDE, don't know how it can be done in headless way... I've ended up to manually export features for multiple platforms and then combine them update site xml to make a complete package.

Answer (score 2):

you should take a look at tycho.
it is a mavne plugin that can generates headless product and update-sites
tycho is a [eclipse project](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Reference_Card) by now

Comment: thanks, I'll keep an eye on this project, right now it seems to be in incubation and don't have much useful information

Comment: nope, it's not on 'incubation' status :) you can follow [this](http://mattiasholmqvist.se/2010/03/building-with-tycho-part-2-rcp-applications/) tutorial to get started. mail list is always a good choice too